# How can I order by random in Laravel Meilisearch and Scout

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I have a query that fetches data using Meilisearch. However, ordering with `orderBy(' RAND() ')` does not work and returns the following error message.

> "message": "Attribute `RAND()` is not sortable. Available sortable
> attributes are: `created_at, updated_at`.",

I've tried to add 'RAND()' as a sortable attribute, but it does not work. Instead, it keeps the default order by. Is there a way to order the result of Meilisearch with RAND()?